# OpenShift access via terminal (SSH) [Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).]

Tags: ssh

I'm currently sitting on Ubuntu and would like remote access to my application on OpenShift. I have done the following to create a ssh-rsa key (I've replaced the fingerprint with xx:xx...):

```
> mkdir ~/.ssh
> chmod 700 ~/.ssh
> ssh-keygen -t rsa                                      
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/karl/.ssh/id_rsa): openshiftKey
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in openshiftKey.
Your public key has been saved in openshiftKey.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx karl@karllaptop
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|                 |
... the rest of the image
```

This creates two files(notice they are not in ~/.ssh):

```
~/openshiftKey
~/openshiftKey.pub
```

I do not know where these files belong, the examples and tutorials say nothing of moving them.

I open the openshiftKey.pub and copy the code:

[image]

I paste it into Openshift:

[image]

Click save:

[image]

Go back to the application settings page and copy the ssh link:

[image]

And on my terminal try and connect:

[image]

I am sorry as I am new to ssh in this degree, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also, there's no need to obfuscate information that's _meant_ to be public.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm guessing the said user would need my generated `openshiftKey` file if that was the case to gain access?

Comment: The _public_ key is meant to be handed out to everyone. The _private_ key you must keep private.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Couldn't someone else *mimic* being me?

Comment: [Off to Wikipedia with you!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a problem:

```
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/karl/.ssh/id_rsa): openshiftKey
```

You didn't accept the default, and gave your key a specific filename.

If you had accepted the default, then ssh would simply look in that default location anytime you make a remote connection to anywhere, and try to use that key.

In order to use a key other than the default key, you have to specify it explicitly when using ssh, for instance:

```
ssh -i $HOME/openshiftKey bad-example.rhcloud.com
```

But you'll probably want to put the key into its default location, so that you can use the `rhc` command line tool to manage your gears. Trying to feed it ssh options is ... rather hairy.

Comment: Ah thanks for clearing that up, may I ask where *should* these files reside?

Comment: Well it _did_ give you the default location right on screen...

Comment: Doh! Now I see it, none of the tutorials mentioned the default key! Anyways it now works as it should, thank you good Sir!